# dd() not showing image - Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

**I have this form:**

```
<form action="{{ route('posts.store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">                   
      @csrf
      <div class="form-group">
           <label for="title">Title</label>
           <input class="form-control w-100" type="text" name="title" id="title">
      </div>   
      <div class="form-group">
           <label for="description">Description</label>
           <textarea name="description" id="description" cols="5" rows="5" class="form-control"</textarea>
      </div>   
      <div class="form-group">
           <label for="content">Content</label>
           <textarea name="content" id="content" cols="5" rows="5" class="form-control"></textarea>
      </div> 
      <div class="form-group">
           <label for="published_at">Published At</label>
           <input class="form-control w-100" type="text" name="published_at" id="published_at">
      </div>  

      <div class="form-group">
           <label for="image">Image</label>
           <input class="form-control w-100" type="file" name="image" id="image">
      </div>  
      <div class="form-group">
           <button class="btn btn-success mt-4" type="submit">
               Create Post          
           </button>   
      </div>                     
</form>
```

**With this migration setup**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('description'); 
            $table->text('content'); 
            $table->timestamp('published_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**The store() method in the Controller**

```
public function store(CreatePostsRequest $request)
    {        
        dd($request->all());

        //session()->flash('success', 'Image uploaded successfully');
        //return redirect(route('posts.index'));
    }
```

**The set of validation rules**

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return [           
            'title' =>'required|unique:posts',           
            'description' => 'required',
            'image' => 'image',
            'content' => 'required'
        ];
    }
```

**When I fill out the form and submit it, dd() displays everything but the image information.**

[image]

**The image is attaching to the form, as seen when I use this specific style input:**

```
 <div class="form-group">
     <label for="image">Image</label>
     <input class="form-control w-100" type="file" name="image" id="image">
 </div>
```

But the end result is still the same; the image is not submitting.
Of course, I want to get to the point of storing images but I am getting stuck here.
I see nothing wrong with my code. Any suggestions?

Comment: I've tried your code and I get the image properly. Did you select an image?

Comment: your code looks correct, but try to stop your rules for now and try to `dd` your request

Comment: Your HTML also has validation errors. Please use a validator and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses, guys. You are correct that the code is correct. I was trying to load images from a personal file. Although the image name appeared in the form when I selected it, nothing more than that happened upon submission. But selecting an image from anywhere else on my computer showed the die-dump on the image effectively working.